# Pascal's triangle

Tags: lisp, scheme

> ```
>     1
>    1 1
>   1 2 1
>  1 3 3 1
> ```

What do you think of this solution for computing Pascal's triangle?

```
(define (pascal row column)
  (cond ((or (= row column) (= 1 column)) 1)
        (else (+ (pascal (- row 1) (- column 1)) 
                 (pascal (- row 1) column)))))
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use [memoization](http://community.schemewiki.org/?memoization) to reduce your algorithm's complexity from O(2 ^ n) to O(n ^ 2).